# How to extend MKPointAnnotation and add a property to it

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I'm trying to extend MKPointAnnotation and add a property to for an NSString called dealLink.

I thought I set it up correctly, but I'm getting this error at the moment:

```
 Property 'dealLink' not found on object of type 'MKPointAnnotation *'
```

Here's my code in a view controller called MapOffersViewController.m:

```
#pragma mark - Populate Map
- (void)populateMap:(MKMapView*)map withDeals:(NSArray*) deals
{
    NSLog(@"Deals " );
    for (NSDictionary *currentDeal in deals) {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D  ctrpoint;
        ctrpoint.latitude = [[[currentDeal objectForKey:@"coords"] objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
        ctrpoint.longitude =[[[currentDeal objectForKey:@"coords"] objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue];

        MKPointAnnotation  *dealAnnotation   = [[MKPointAnnotation  alloc] init];

        dealAnnotation.coordinate = ctrpoint;
        dealAnnotation.title = [currentDeal objectForKey:@"vendor"];
        **dealAnnotation.dealLink = [currentDeal objectForKey:@"link"];**

        NSDictionary *currDict = @{
        @"EUR": @"€",
        @"GBP": @"₤",
        @"USD": @"$",
        @"BRL": @"R$"
        };

        NSString *currName = [currentDeal objectForKey:@"currency"];
        NSString *currency = [currDict objectForKey:currName];

        dealAnnotation.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i",currency,[[currentDeal objectForKey:@"price"] integerValue ]];

        NSLog(@"current deal id is %@",[currentDeal objectForKey:@"id"]);

        [map setDelegate:self];
        [map addAnnotation:dealAnnotation];
    }
}
```

I'm importing this class called MapAnnotation.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapAnnotation : MKPointAnnotation
{
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;
    NSString *dealLink;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *dealLink;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl subTitle:(NSString *)subttl dealLink:(NSString *)dealLnk andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d;

@end
```

and it's .m:

```
#import "MapAnnotation.h"

@implementation MapAnnotation

@synthesize title,subtitle,dealLink,coordinate;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl subTitle:(NSString *)subttl dealLink:(NSString *)dealLnk andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d {
    title = ttl;
    subtitle = subttl;
    dealLink = dealLnk;
    coordinate = c2d;

    return self;
}

@end
```

thanks for any help

I used Craig's answer below and this additional code to get this working:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {


    NSLog(@"callout tapped from del method %@", dealUrl);

   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dealUrl]];

}


- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView1 didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)mapView2
{
    MapAnnotation *annotation = mapView2.annotation;
    NSString *temp = annotation.dealLink;

    dealUrl = temp;

 //   NSLog(@"temp is %@", temp);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating an MKPointAnnotation and trying to access dealLink, which is only on MapAnnotations. You need to create a MapAnnotation

```
....
ctrpoint.longitude =[[[currentDeal objectForKey:@"coords"] objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue];

MapAnnotation  *dealAnnotation   = [[MapAnnotation  alloc] init];

dealAnnotation.coordinate = ctrpoint;
....
```

Comment: thanks! I tried that and when I 
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {
    
    NSLog(@"callout tapped from del method %@", dealAnnotation.title);
    
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dealAnnotation.dealLink]];

} the dealAnnotation.dealLink is the same no matter which map view annotation is touched.

Comment: Of course it is. Every time `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` gets called `dealAnnotation` has the same value. Instead of accessing `dealAnnotation` which is set somewhere else and doesn't change every time you touch the screen, you should be using the MKAnnotationView that has been tapped and asking it for the right annotation.