# Adding third property to MKPointAnnotation / calloutAccessoryControlTapped

Tags: xcode, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I have been trying to pass three points of data from an MKMapView pin to my next view controller.

I am able to pass the title and subtitle without problem now, using calloutAccessoryControlTapped, but am having great difficulty getting a third parameter passed.

I have been trying to follow this SO question [How to extend MKPointAnnotation and add a property to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15134382/how-to-extend-mkpointannotation-and-add-a-property-to-it)

My current code is...

In my first ViewController .m file

```
#import "MapAnnotation.h"

- (void)loadMapPins {
  for (int i=0; i<_feedItems1.count; i++){
    Location *item = _feedItems1[i];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D myCoordinate = {[item.latitude doubleValue], [item.longitude doubleValue]};
    MapAnnotation *point = [[MapAnnotation alloc] init];
    point.coordinate = myCoordinate;
    point.title = item.firstname;
    point.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", item.time];
    point.dealLink = item.username;
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
  }
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id )annotation {
  if (annotation == self.mapView.userLocation) return nil;
  static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";
  MKPinAnnotationView* customPin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
  customPin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
  customPin.animatesDrop = YES;
  customPin.canShowCallout = YES;
  UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
  customPin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
  return customPin;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {
  NSLog(@"title = %@", view.annotation.title);
  NSLog(@"subtitle = %@", view.annotation.subtitle);
  NSLog(@"title = %@", view.annotation.dealLink);
}
```

And I have created the other files, as per the above SO question...

MapAnnotation.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapAnnotation : MKPointAnnotation
{
NSString *title;
NSString *subtitle;
NSString *dealLink;
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *dealLink;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl subTitle:(NSString *)subttl dealLink:(NSString *)dealLnk andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d;

@end
```

And MapAnnotation.m

```
#import "MapAnnotation.h"

@implementation MapAnnotation

@synthesize title,subtitle,dealLink,coordinate;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl subTitle:(NSString *)subttl dealLink:(NSString *)dealLnk andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d {
title = ttl;
subtitle = subttl;
dealLink = dealLnk;
coordinate = c2d;

return self;
}

@end
```

But I always get "proper dealLink not found on object of type 'id'" in my calloutAccessoryControlTapped method.

Any help or advice? This is driving me nuts trying to get three parameters passed!!!